# How to change defaults in oracle docker image

Tags: oracle, docker

I have been trying to change a few defaults in the database and set a language in default oracle docker image, but I have been failing. I have been trying to

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET NLS_LANGUAGE = 'GERMAN' SCOPE=SPFILE;
```

I have done

```
create pfile from spfile
```

Confirmed that the data is changed and then

```
create spfile from pfile
```

Didn't work. Restarted between both steps. I did it after logging in with all of these options:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
sqlplus sys@FREE as sysdba
```

None worked. I am checking by

```
SELECT * FROM nls_database_parameters;
```

The parameters I want to change are: NLS_LANGUAGE, NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT, NLS_DATE_FORMAT, NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT, NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS, NLS_CURRENCY,NLS_TERRITORY

My setup is completely within this docker compose file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  database:
    image: container-registry.oracle.com/database/free:latest
    environment:
      - ORACLE_PWD=<SomePassword>
    volumes:
      - database:/opt/oracle/oradata
    ports:
      - 1521:1521

volumes:
  database:
```

What is the correct way to set the language so that the database created by docker image provided by oracle will have language I specified? I also tried:

- setting the environment of the container during startup(NLS_LANG, NLS_LANGUAGE, NLS_TERRITORY) - the most I got is some messages in sqlplus were in German.
- mounting the file init.ora.8220235419 (it was the one I found) with my own values before database creation.

It is not the issue of trying to change nls settings in existing database - I want to create a new database with language I want.

Comment: "will be retained after restart" -- restart of what exactly? If you restart the container, and its configuration files are part of the image, then every time you restart the container they will revert to whatever they are in the image.

Comment: `NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS` reflects the values that were in effect when the database was created. Even if you manage to change it, setting parameters like `nls_language` on the database server makes little to no sense, it may be overriden at session level by clients based on the clients regional setting or any custom value. You are looking for a solution to a derived problem. So what is your original problem? If you want your database to communicate with you in a different language, changing database defaults is not the way to do that. Change the settings of your client and its session.

Comment: Retained after restart of the database, not deleting of the container. I want the session defaults to be of certain language - if I need to recreate the whole database that's ok.  I know it can be changed per session, but I need it to be in certain language by default

Answer (score 0):

Use environmental variables. This is the recommended approach for setting NLS settings during container startup. Define them in the environment section of your docker-compose file for the database service

```
    database:
      image: container-registry.oracle.com/database/free:latest
      environment:
    - ORACLE_PWD=<SomePassword>
    - NLS_LANGUAGE=GERMAN
    - NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT=DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS
    - NLS_DATE_FORMAT=DD.MM.YYYY
    - NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT='HH24:MI'
    - NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=".,'"
    - NLS_CURRENCY='€'
    - NLS_TERRITORY='DE'
```

These additional environment variables define the other desired NLS settings. Be sure to replace the values with your specific preferences.